# Trigger to find changed columns in table A and then use changed column names as data on INSERT to table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table that inserts the status of a sensor every second.  It does this by inserting a 0 or 1 into every column in the table.  It will do an insert every second regardless.  There are currently just 10 or so columns but this will grow to 100 or so in the near future.  The table details are below.  I know this is a horrible way to store this data but I cannot control how this data is inserted.

I want to use an after insert trigger to see what columns have changed from a 0 to a 1 and insert a record into a new table, details below, with the old tables column name that changed in a field called MACHINE and the current timestamp in a column called START.  I also want the trigger to watch for columns that have changed from a 1 to a 0 and do an update on the new table by changing the column called STOP to the current timestamp.  This way I wind up with a new table that has the start and stop times the sensors were on and I can then delete records over a day old off the old table daily to keep it small.

Doing a regular trigger with an insert or delete I have done but looping through columns and then using the actual column name as data for a row in the new table sounds daunting.  Is this possible without writing pages of code?

Old Table Columns - ID, ENTRYTIME, MACHINENAME(Many of these columns with slightly different names)

New Table Columns - ID, MACHINENAME, START, STOP

I hope I explained this well enough.  Thanks for any help.

UPDATED:  Added some original data and assumed new table layout

```
ID  DATETIME    M1L1 M1L2 M1L3 M2L1 M2L2 M2L3 M2L4
1   10:25.01      0    0    0    0    0    0    1
2   10:26.02      0    0    0    0    0    0    1
3   10:27.03      0    0    1    0    0    0    1
4   10:28.04      0    0    1    0    0    0    1
5   10:29.05      0    1    0    0    0    0    0
6   10:30.06      0    1    0    0    0    1    0
7   10:31.07      0    1    0    0    0    1    0
8   10:32.08      0    1    0    0    0    1    0
9   10:33.09      0    0    0    0    0    1    0
10  10:34.10      0    0    0    0    0    1    0
11  10:35.11      0    0    0    0    0    1    0
12  10:36.12      0    0    0    0    0    1    0
13  10:37.13      0    0    0    0    1    1    0
```

New table would be:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_B
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MACHINENAME] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
[START] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[STOP] [datetime] NULL
```

Or the new table could be:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_B
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MACHINENAME] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
[START] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[DURATION] [time] NULL
```

where [DURATION] was the calculated length of time the sensor was "1"

I also threw together a trigger that would not work yet but should bet my thoughts across as to what I am wanting (maybe).

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_FIND_CHANGES
   ON  TABLE_A
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE_B
    SELECT  TABLE_A.MACHINENAME, --NEED TO CYCLE THROUGH ALL COLUMNS
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS [START]
    FROM    INSERTED A JOIN
            TABLE_A A ON INSERTED.ID = A.ID - 1 --MATCH INSERTED ROW ID TO PREVIOUS ROW ID
    WHERE   INSERTED.MACHINENAME > A.MACHINENAME --LOOK FOR WHEN CHANGED FROM 0 TO 1


    UPDATE  TABLE_B
    SET     TABLE_B.[STOP] = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM    INSERTED A JOIN
            TABLE_A A ON INSERTED.ID = A.ID - 1 --MATCH INSERTED ROW ID TO PREVIOUS ROW ID
    WHERE   INSERTED.MACHINENAME < A.MACHINENAME --LOOK FOR WHEN CHANGED FROM 1 TO 0

END
```

Comment: Do you have a trigger you have tried, it would be worth adding to your question?

Comment: No, started writing the trigger many times but could not figure out how to cycle through columns and how to use column names as data for the insert correctly.  I will try to write a dummy trigger to show my intent though.

Comment: This can be done, but *not* efficiently.  Also, if the number of columns is not a fixed thing, then they probably shouldn't be separate columns in a relational database.  You should probably rethink this design.

Comment: The number of columns will eventually be fixed once the machines are all upgraded but that will be happening over a few months.  I agree the design is the problem (at least from my viewpoint) but I cannot change how the original table is populated.  I am just looking for a way to store the data in a simpler way in a new table and then I can delete older records from the original table regularly.

Comment: "Fixed" until a new machine is added or one is removed. This is just awful. Why is there another column for each machine? This is obviously still being created...the time to fix this abomination of an architecture is now. If you don't do it right from the beginning you will never go back and fix it. It really will be too late in the future.

Comment: I agree but am not finding a solution.  The software that is populating the original table is a data logging application that is reading the data from a USB connected receiver that is receiving its data from the machines.  This software is taking this simplest, but worst, method to logging the data by just seeing what the current status is each second and writing it to a table. I am looking for different software to log this data from the USB connection better but I am not finding any.

Comment: Ugh that is unfortunate. If you can provide the actual table structure and a few rows of sample data along with the desired output of the sample data we can probably figure something out that will help.

Comment: Also, efficiency is NOT a major concern for this.  This SQL server is a standalone server with almost nothing else running on it.  I hope to send the data from the new table to another well planned and used SQL server where I can do reporting and communicating based on the data.